# Android's BuiltInZoom doesn't work in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm developing a hybrid app on Android that displays HTML on WebView.
I want to zoom the screen by pinch-out, but BuiltInZoom doesn't work (can't zoom in/out) when I get a touch event on the JavaScript side.
It occurs with Pixel 4 (Android 10), but it works correctly with Pixel 3 (Android 9).

### What I've already tried

- If I don't get a touch event in JavaScript, I can zoom in and out.
- Since pinch event is called on onScale, I can get current span and apply on onDraw.
- However, this is undesirable because it does not reflect the "maximum-scale" of the HTML "viewport". I want to control the maximum magnification according to the "viewport".

I get the touch event as follow.

```
view.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  console.log('touchstart');
});
view.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  console.log('touchmove');
});
```

I set BuiltInZoom to enable on Android.

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

### Note

- It occurs with Pixel 4 (Android 10) and Galaxy Tab S4 (Android 9), but it works correctly with Pixel 3 (Android 9).
- I can zoom by using zoom controls, but it was already deprecated.
- I can zoom after long pressing on screen with one finger.
- I can zoom when placing one finger on an element that I don't get touch event.
- onScale is called whenever I operate pinch action.
- WebViewClient.onScaleChanged is only called when it can be scaled.
- I change the "maximum-scale" of the HTML "viewport" dynamically because some pages are allowed to be zoomed and others are not.

Answer (score 0):

I can zoom by ignoring ACTION_POINTER_DOWN in WebView.onTouchEvent.
But suddenly it's zoomed largely because there is no position.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
        return false;
    }

    super.onTouchEvent(ev);

    return true;
}
```